# YARN: No Active Cluster Nodes

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I successfully installed Hadoop and can see all `ResourceManager` on master node and `NodeManager` on slave nodes. But When I check on http://hadoop-master:8088/cluster, it showed no active cluster nodes. 
I also checked the Yarn's logs, it said `java.net.ConnectException: Your endpoint configuration is wrong; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/UnsetHostnameOrPort`
But I don't know what I did wrong, here is the configuration:

```
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
<value>hadoop-master</value>
</configuration>
```

As the image here, not active nodes :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/giumQ.png

jps on slave nodes:

```
9011 DataNode
10093 NodeManager
10446 Jps
```

jps on Master node:

```
32546 ResourceManager
25176 NameNode
25643 SecondaryNameNode
17629 Jps
```

Comment: Please show all relevant yarn-site.xml files from both servers

Comment: Nothing more, I just set like above, and in the yarn-site.xml on master node, I left it blank `<configuration></configuration>`

Comment: Okay, then how does the master know it needs to be the master? Have you read this? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HADOOP2/UnsetHostnameOrPort

Answer (score 1):

Check if hostname is correct wich machine
`<name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>`
`<value>hadoop-master</value>`
`</configuration>`